# How can I check each result on a function and then go to the other function?

Tags: php

I have data in a json file that I want to search for in Google search engine, Bing search engine and Yahoo search engine
But I want to check the data one by one
For example, the first statement is checked on Google, and the second statement is checked on Bing, and the third statement is checked on Yahoo

```
$DataCodeFile = __DIR__ . '\datacheck.json';
$DataCode = file_get_contents($DataCodeFile);
$DataCode_Data = json_decode($DataCode,true);

$DataNumber = $DataCode_Data[mt_rand(0,count($DataCode_Data)-1)];



function check1() {

  $curl_handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.google.com');
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ''.$DataNumber.'');
  $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  curl_close($curl_handle);
  
   }
   
   
   
function check2() {

  $curl_handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.bing.com');
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ''.$DataNumber.'');
  $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  curl_close($curl_handle);
  
   }
   
   
function check3() {

  $curl_handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.example.com');
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ''.$DataNumber.'');
  $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  curl_close($curl_handle);
  
   }
 
  
  
    $funcarr = array ("check1", "check2", "check3");

    $funrand = $funcarr[mt_rand(0,count($funcarr)-1)];

  
  
  $res = $funrand();
if (!strstr($res)) echo "found 1";
else echo "not found";
```

Comment: Just call them one after the other. What have you tried? Unclear specifically what the issue is

Comment: how can i call them one after the other ?
 check the value once only

Comment: Do you wish to pass the result of one function to another and so on?

Comment: Currently you have an obvious SCOPE issue. `$buffer` only exists inside the functions, and each `$buffer` is a seperate version of `$buffer` So `if (empty($buffer)){` will generate a variable does not exists error

Comment: `how can i call them one after the other`... line 1, call function 1. Line 2, call function 2. One line after another. I feel like you're actually trying to ask something more complicated than that, but somehow not saying it clearly.

Comment: At a guess, are you maybe actually asking how to check the response from the first function, and only run the second function if the first was successful?

Comment: But in order to do that, you'll first have to make your functions `return` something. I feel like maybe you need to take another tutorial or two about functions, because I think perhaps you have not understood all the basic concepts, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: `I want to check the data one by one`...my answer below already does that. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check the result of a function, the function first needs to return something.

Your request is a bit vague, but maybe this is what you mean? It calls each function, echoes whether a response was received or not, and then calls the next one:

```
function check1() {
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return $buffer;
}

function check2() {
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.bing.com');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return $buffer;
}

function check3() {
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.example.com');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return $buffer;

}

$res1 = check1();
if (!empty($res1)) echo "found 1";
else echo "not found 1";

$res2 = check2();
if (!empty($res2)) echo "found 2";
else echo "not found 2";

$res3 = check3();
if (!empty($res3)) echo "found 3";
else echo "not found 3";
```

If you want it so that the 2nd and 3rd functions are only executed if the previous one(s) found a result, then you'll need to adjust the `if` statements accordingly.

N.B. The `$func` arguments to each function seemed to be redundant, so I removed them.

Comment: I need to check all the values ​​but each value is on a function
If the result is found, it will print it, and if not found, it will also print a not found

Comment: Each value is checked on a function and not checked on all functions

Comment: `If the result is found, it will print it, and if not found, it will also print a not found`...yes that's what my code would do. Or you mean you want to echo the actual result rather then the word "found"?

Comment: `Each value is checked on a function and not checked on all functions`...this doesn't really make sense, sorry. Please clarify what you mean exactly.

Comment: plss see my Answers up Is this good or not?

Comment: can you see my edit now

Answer (score 0):

You should return the `$buffer`. By the way, you are not ussing the `$func` parameter so you don't really need it.

```
function check1() {
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return $buffer;
}
```

Then, you can just call the functions sequentially and assign their return value to a variable, doing the checks as you go:

```
$buffer1 = check1()
if (!empty($buffer1)) {
    echo 'Check1 - found!'
    $buffer2 = check2()
    if (!empty($buffer2) {
        echo 'Check2 - found!'
        $buffer3 = check3()
        if (!empty($buffer3) {
            echo 'Check3 - found!'
        }
    }
}
```

And obviously you can `echo` the buffers in whenever you want. You can make this code better, but this way should be easy to understand.